# Collage in a Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a Wordpress theme for one of our clients and their "About Us" page contains a page full of photos of people/ employees, of two different sizes, board of directors in large photos and others in smaller images. How do I design a page for this so that the photos fit the screen well. Is there any free plugin that could be of help or a way to implement without plugins ?? Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Take a look at implementing jQuery Masonry - fitting variable sized images/html in the most space efficient way possible is what it's all about.

http://masonry.desandro.com